# Creating a BufferedReader or BufferedWriter from a File*Stream

Tags: java

Is there any difference to using the first as opposed the second code whean creating a reader (or a writer)?

```
 BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("name.txt")),"UTF-8"));

 BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("name.txt"),"UTF-8"));
```

Does br1 create 2 buffers, one for characters one for bytes?

Comment: There's no benefit from the extra BufferedInputStream.

Comment: Double buffering will do more harm than good. Just use [`Files.newBufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)) and throw this whole mess away.

Comment: @BoristheSpider that method does seem more practical,what I wrote is what we have in our presentation slides in class. Guess they're trying to make us learn both java.io and java.nio